# Quick.db, SQLite database file wiping on Bot reboot. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to save a value of the server being "Down" or "Up", it seems to be working fine, however, when I clear the console, then run the bot again, it looks to have reset the database fully, is there a way to make the database, work like a normal database would? (Save after restart)

I'm having a check to see if the server is up, then don't allow it to run the command and say it's already online.

I wasn't like this before, and I haven't used quick.db for a while, so sorry if I missed anything.

Code:

```js
// Main requirements
const { ROLE_SSUPIN, CHANNEL_SSU, CHANNEL_ROLESEL, BOT_PREFIX } = require('../../config.json')
const commandName = 'ssu'

// Optional Requirements
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db');
const db = new QuickDB();

// Main Code
module.exports = async client => {
    client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(BOT_PREFIX)) return;

        const command = message.content.split(' ')
        const args = message.content.substring(1).split(' ')

        if (command.toString().toLowerCase().replace(BOT_PREFIX, '').startsWith(commandName)) {
            const ssuStatus = await db.get("ssu.status")
            await db.set("ssu.status", "down");
            console.log(ssuStatus)

            if (!message.member.roles.cache.get('998320362234323026')) return message.reply("Only staff with `SSU Permissions` can use this command!")//.then(m => {setTimeout( function() { m.delete(), message.delete() }, 10000)});

            if (!message.channel.id == CHANNEL_SSU) return message.reply(`Please use this command in <#${CHANNEL_SSU}>.`)
            if (ssuStatus == 'up') return message.reply(`Server Status is already set to Online. Say \`${BOT_PREFIX}Server Status Set Offline\` if you believe this is a mistake.`)

message.channel.send(`
Start up done.
`)
.then(await db.set("ssu.status", "up"))

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: FYI answers (or announcements of being solved) don't belong in questions. I rolled back your edit, accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `"await db.set("ssu.status", "down");"` in the start of each function, so it was reseting it back to "Down", I didn't mean for it do that, if you have the same issue, make sure that you don't have anything that sets the database value in the start, as it might be the reason it's getting reset and you think it's wiping.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).